# Offline audio playlist app on iPhone?

Tags: audio, offline, iphone-app

I'm trying to find a simple app that can take MP3 files, preferably from iCloud cache (the iPhone's local storage) and arrange them in a playlist.

VLC is *supposed* to be able to do this, but when I try to load the MP3 files in, it is hit-or-miss: sometimes I get duplicates, sometimes the MP3 doesn't get added to the playlist at all.

What would be a good iOS app for this? Preferably free but doesn't have to be.

Comment: I'm happily using OPlayer, but as a Linux user I dont' use the iPhone internal storage, icloud, etc. but I recall seeing those options as a source for files.  It does let you build play lists of whatever files it can see though.

Comment: Seems like OPlayer fits the bill, yes! Much thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happily using OPlayer, but as a Linux user I dont' use the iPhone internal storage, icloud, etc. but I recall seeing those options as a source for files. It does let you build play lists of whatever files it can see though.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again, @ivanivan!